# Read this multilevel array in parts PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I will have this type of array in PHP:

```
$data = array(
    array(1 => array("A ROW GREENS", array(
        "A1" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"),
        "A2" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"),
        "A3" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg")
    ))),
    array(2 => array("A ROW BLUE",array(
        "A1" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"),
        "A2" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"),
        "A3" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg")
    ))),

);
```

I will need to read it from parts.

First part:
I need recover "A ROW GREENS", "A ROW BLUE".. and this level in this part.

Second part:
I need here the A1,A2,A3,..... with the associateds url

I tried split the parts with some for combinations without success.. Any help?

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    foreach($value as $main=>$second){
        foreach($second as $seconda=>$secondb){

        print_r($secondb);
        echo "<br><hr>";

        }
    }
}
```

Desired output:

```
<ul id="parent">
    <li id="1">A ROW GREENS</li>
    <li id="2">A ROW BLUE</li>
</ul>
...
```

More later I need:

```
<ul id="child1">
    <li class="parent1">A1</li>
    <li class="parent1">A2</li>
</ul>
<ul id="child2">
    <li class="parent2">A1</li>
    <li class="parent2">A2</li>
</ul>
...
```

Finally, other `<ul>` with the URLs, but these will be easy since I will have the second part.

(Don't worry about the ids, it's only for the visual relations in the code)

Comment: Please show your desired output. That will make it clearer.

Comment: You asked yesterday and then abandoned the question and then asked a new one.

Comment: Not really, people change the discussion topic an then go out, This have a different data structure and all the detail. Thanks for the comment